# How to call json from php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have written a php code that should print the response of a json call. But I am getting NULL output. I have checked my json call is working fine from a restclient.

Here is my code

```
<?php

    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";

    $postData = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'msisdn' => "111111111"
            );

    $ch = curl_init('http://ip:<port>/xxx/yyy/zzz');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Decode the response
    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    // Print the date from the response
    echo $responseData['published'];

    var_dump($responseData);

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($response)` and see what response you are getting.

Comment: have you checked, if your $response actually contains JSON-code, and if so, if it is valid?

Comment: Try `print_r(json_last_error());`

Comment: `var_dump($response)` is giving HTTP Status 500 with following exception -

`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "username"`

Comment: @Pemapmodder `print_r(json_last_error());` gave 4 as output which is a syntax error right?

Comment: Yep. Actually I meant `json_last_error_msg()`, but yes, 4 means syntax error. So yes, use @Vladimir Kovpak's method to automatically check if server has an error.

Comment: Well, this means you have provided a wrong key in your *$postData*. *"username"* is not a valid key it seems, so find out what the right key is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so i have solved my problem and re-wrote the code. I was actually not providing the correct form of username and password in the json fields which is really a silly mistake.
I am giving my updated code here 
`

```
$data = array("user" => "$username", "pass" => "$password", "msisdn" => "$msisdn");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://ip:port/call_center/account/general');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;


?>`
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid JSON.');
}
```

Comment: i got `Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in` exception

Comment: It mean that you don't receive json, or not valid json.